# Bootstrap breadcrumb not working inside tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've included a breadcrumb at the top of two separate pages for prototyping purposes, which works on the first few clicks. However, it seems that somehow the breadcrumb is being activated and disabling the link.

```
<div id="example" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="overview">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li>Overview</li>
    </ol>
    <p><a href="#content" data-parent="#example" data-toggle="tab">Content</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="content">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#overview" data-parent="#tabs" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ol>
    <p><a href="#overview" data-parent="#example" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My guess is that I'm using the breadcrumb incorrectly, but as I'm developing this for a prototype, I'm not sure how else to use it.

Comment: I noticed that I had an incorrect data-parent in the second breadcrumb below the id="content" but changing this to #example had no impact. Somehow the list item for overview is being given an active class. Removing this class enables the functionality, but it breaks once more after clicking on the list item link a second time.

Comment: Not sure why this issue is hinging on the active class, but I've removed it with jQuery when the link is clicked. Seems to be working fine now.

    $('.breadcrumb li a').on('click', function () {
        $('.breadcrumb li').removeClass('active');
    });